# "expected bound lifetime parameter" error when attempting to call a generic function

Tags: rust

I am attempting to write a function that validates a given collection using a closure. The function takes ownership of a collection, iterates over the contents, and if no invalid item was found, returns ownership of the collection. This is so it can be used like this (without creating a temp for the `Vec`): `let col = validate(vec![1, 2], |&v| v < 10)?;`

This is the current implementation of the function:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn validate<C, F, V>(col: C, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = V>,
          F: Fn(&V) -> bool,
          V: Debug
{
    if let Some(val) = (&col).into_iter().find(|v| !pred(v)) {
        Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", col, val))?;
    }
    Ok(col)
}
```

It does compile, but it doesn't work when I try to use it:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::iter::{FromIterator, once};

fn main() {
    println!("Vec: {:?}", validate(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], |&&v| v <= 3));
    //                    ^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter 'c, found concrete lifetime

    println!("Map: {:?}",
             validate(BTreeMap::from_iter(once((1, 2))), |&(&k, &v)| k <= 3));
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f7e126c263fa1acd5da4a2b74dd83f17)

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here possible?

### Background

I am writing a parser for a toy project of mine and was wondering if I
could write a single `validate` function that works with all the collection
types I use:
[Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)s,
[VecDeque](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html)s,
[BTreeSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html)s,
[BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html)s,
[&[T] slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html).

Each of these collections implements the `IntoIterator` trait for a reference of itself,
which can be used to call `.into_iter()` on a reference without consuming the items
in the collection:

- [Vec impl](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1f965cc8e9dc8f8b26eac99cffdef6501cf0c617/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1547)
- [VecDeque impl](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1f965cc8e9dc8f8b26eac99cffdef6501cf0c617/src/libcollections/vec_deque.rs#L2238)
- [BTreeSet impl](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1f965cc8e9dc8f8b26eac99cffdef6501cf0c617/src/libcollections/btree/set.rs#L648)
- [BTreeMap impl](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1f965cc8e9dc8f8b26eac99cffdef6501cf0c617/src/libcollections/btree/map.rs#L1131)
- [&[T] slices impl](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1f965cc8e9dc8f8b26eac99cffdef6501cf0c617/src/libcore/slice.rs#L935)

This is the what the `for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = V>` in the function declaration
refers to. Since the reference is defined **in** the function body itself, we can't just
use a lifetime that's declared on the function (like `fn validate<'c, ...`), because this
would imply that the reference has to outlive the function (which it cannot). Instead we
have to use a [Higher-Rank Trait Bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) to
declare this lifetime.

It seems to me that this lifetime is also the source of the trouble, since a version of
the function that takes and returns a reference to the collection works fine:

```
// This works just fine.
fn validate<'c, C, F, V>(col: &'c C, pred: F) -> Result<&'c C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = V>,
          F: Fn(&V) -> bool,
          V: Debug
{
    if let Some(val) = col.into_iter().find(|v| !pred(v)) {
        Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", col, val))?;
    }
    Ok(col)
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5492174f03799af493a41b1e23c652cb)

Furthermore, I managed to implement two other versions of the
function, one which works for `Vec`, `VecDeque`, `BTreeSet` and `&[T] slices`, and another
which works for `BTreeMap` and probably other mappings:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub fn validate_collection<C, F, V>(col: C, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = &'c V>,
          F: Fn(&V) -> bool,
          V: Debug
{
    if let Some(val) = (&col).into_iter().find(|&v| !pred(v)) {
        Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", col, val))?;
    }
    Ok(col)
}

pub fn validate_mapping<C, F, K, V>(col: C, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = (&'c K, &'c V)>,
          F: Fn(&K, &V) -> bool,
          K: Debug,
          V: Debug
{
    if let Some(val) = (&col).into_iter().find(|&(k, v)| !pred(k, v)) {
        Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", col, val))?;
    }
    Ok(col)
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f81dbbaf8ee85bb7f785024e16a4ee6f)

In the end I hope to create a `Validate` trait. Currently, I can only impl
it for either collections or mappings, because the impls conflict.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Validate<V>: Sized {
    fn validate<F>(self, F) -> Result<Self, String> where F: Fn(&V) -> bool;
}

// Impl that only works for collections, not mappings.
impl<C, V> Validate<V> for C
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = &'c V>,
          V: Debug
{
    fn validate<F>(self, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
        where F: Fn(&V) -> bool
    {
        if let Some(val) = (&self).into_iter().find(|&v| !pred(v)) {
            Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", self, val))?;
        }
        Ok(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Vec: {:?}", vec![1, 2, 3, 4].validate(|&v| v <= 3));
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=24f17167a7e755e90de57d36119860eb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your trait bounds (reformatted a little):

```
fn validate<C, F, V>(col: C, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = V>,
          F: Fn(&V) -> bool,
          V: Debug {
```

the problem is that `&C` won't implement `IntoIterator<Item = V>`; references tend to iterate over references.

Fixing that (and the extra reference in the closure) makes it work:

```
fn validate<C, F, V>(col: C, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> &'c C: IntoIterator<Item = &'c V>,
          F: Fn(&V) -> bool,
          V: Debug
{
    if let Some(val) = (&col).into_iter().find(|v| !pred(v)) {
        Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", col, val))?;
    }
    Ok(col)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Vec: {:?}", validate(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], |&v| v <= 3));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e3837b0b8747b684a45cc89e7cbc9ff3&version=stable&backtrace=0)

To extend this to work with `BTreeMap` values, we can abstract over the method used to generate the iterators.   Let's add a trait `HasValueIterator` which knows how to get an iterator over values:

```
trait HasValueIterator<'a, V: 'a> {
    type ValueIter : Iterator<Item=&'a V>;

    fn to_value_iter(&'a self) -> Self::ValueIter;
}
```

and use that instead of `IntoIterator`:

```
fn validate<C, F, V>(col: C, pred: F) -> Result<C, String>
    where C: Debug,
          for<'c> C: HasValueIterator<'c, V>,
          F: Fn(&V) -> bool,
          V: Debug
{
    if let Some(val) = (&col).to_value_iter().find(|v| !pred(v)) {
        Err(format!("{:?} contains invalid item: {:?}.", col, val))?;
    }
    Ok(col)
}
```

Now we can implement it for `Vec` and `BTreeMap` (the latter using `.values()`), thought you have to name the iterator types:

```
impl<'c, V:'c> HasValueIterator<'c, V> for Vec<V> {
    type ValueIter = std::slice::Iter<'c,V>;

    fn to_value_iter(&'c self) -> Self::ValueIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}

impl<'c, V:'c, K:'c> HasValueIterator<'c, V> for BTreeMap<K, V> {
    type ValueIter = std::collections::btree_map::Values<'c, K, V>;

    fn to_value_iter(&'c self) -> Self::ValueIter {
        self.values()
    }

}
```

Now this works with both `Vec` and `BTreeMap`, at least with values:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Vec: {:?}", validate(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], |&v| v <= 3));

    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert("first", 1);
    map.insert("second", 2);
    map.insert("third", 3);
    println!("Map: {:?}", validate(map, |&v| v<=2));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ade6feef1d2054f403bd361aff4e4d67&version=stable&backtrace=0)

This outputs:

```
Vec: Err("[1, 2, 3, 4] contains invalid item: 4.")
Map: Err("{\"first\": 1, \"second\": 2, \"third\": 3} contains invalid item: 3.")
```

Comment: The problem is, BTreeMap references iter over tuples of references: [So this doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9505e5d3c1d13b3ce1d99c5853e3b031&version=stable&backtrace=0). The fix you made only works for collections sadly. I also managed to get a version for mappings working, see the code block containing `validate_collection` and `validate_mapping`.

Comment: Do you want to validate both the key and value, or just the values?

Comment: Preferably both, but if you have a solution for the values I'd be very interested to know how you did that!

Comment: I've updated with a way to work with `BTreeMap` values (but not key/value).

Comment: Thank you, I was expecting there's no way around a custom trait. I think this fits my needs quite nicely though!